# Java code Not running on other system

Tags: spring-mvc

I have developed a simple login application using Spring in Java. The IDE used is Eclipse. The application works in my system but when imported to other systems, it gives 404 error.

Comment: That's probably just an issue of the servlet being mounted on a different context path. Still: if you need help, you will have to post some of your code

Comment: Any error you get in your console output?

Comment: I am getting stackTrace in the web page.

Comment: Do you have the same servers running?

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace to your question?